# How do I update a variable value across modules Python?

Tags: python

I have a main script and I am importing another module with a class in it. When I instantiate the class one of the arguments is `y` and therefore I have an equivalent `self.y = y` in the `__init__` method. Now the problem is that in the main script I have a `for` loop that changes the `y` value and calls the method 'live_plotting' from the same class. I usually have to pass in the `y` value as an argument again and have another `self.y = y` inside the method. This is not neat, is there any way of updating `self.y` across modules without having to pass in as an argument again? I thought of using pointers but apparently everything is a pointer in python. Can anyone offer an alternative solution?

Comment: We won't be able to help you with such a vague question. Provide the code you've written so far, your expected input and output, and a description of why it doesn't work.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I cant provide the entire code because it too much.  The basic structure is there and I'm asking a question regarding updating variables across modules not about my code.

Comment: Also the code requires knowledge of matplotlib, so a regular programmer wouldn't understand it. So Im asking a general question about modules.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This would be much easier to receive help this way, even though your question is about a general topic

Comment: @BusyAnt I have added it

Comment: You don't want to pass `y` as an argument from the `live_plotting(self,BOOLEAN, y )` function ?

Comment: @pwnsauce No, I want to somehow update the self.y value instead of passing it as an argument (remember that the y value changes as the for loop iterates).

Comment: You'll have to give `y` as an argument somewhere. Either here or in a mutator, but I don't see how you could update `attribute without giving the value somewhere.

Comment: @pwnsauce 

When I instantiate the class, I assign it to self.y, is there any way I could point to the value of y like in C language?   

How would I go about creating a mutator?

Comment: If I understand correcly : you want that each time `y` is modified, `self.y` is also modified? maybe instead of using `y` you just use `InstanceName.y` where instanceName is the name of the object you instanciated. Mutator have to be defined in the class : `def set_y(self,y) : self.y=y` and you use it : InstanceName.set_y(value)

Comment: Yes that's what I want, but I am creating these functions in class funcs for an engineer to be able to easily write r.live_plotting(True) instead of passing in the y value as an argument. Is there any way of doing this with a mutator? What is a mutator?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117718/discussion-between-mariano-and-pwnsauce).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure if it's what you want, but from my understanding you want to update the value of self.y without a method?

This would be done by executing

```
object_name.y = new_value
```

where `object_name` is the name you gave the instance of your Class, seeing as *self* variables declared in the `__init__` are attributes that belong to that instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

From what i've understand, mutator arn't what you are looking for.
A mutator is a function within a class that access an attribut and modify it's value.

I think in your code, you want to use `y` as if `self.y` and `y` where linked to each others. But when you give `y` as an argument to a function, then `self.y = y` the `y` in the function is a copie of the `y` you passed as an argument. then `self.y = y` take the value of the copied `y` and store it in `self.y`.

After instanciating your object :

```
my_instance = class(x,y)
#if you want to modify my_instance.y
my_instance.y = value
```

or with a mutator in the class :

```
def set_y(self,value):
    self.y=value
```

then in your main when you want to modify y :

```
my_instance.set_y(value)
```